# Email POP3 forwards from Hotmail to Gmail take too long?

Tags: outlook.com, email-forwarding

I am forwarding email from my Hotmail to Gmail account. Typically it's taking at least an hour before it arrives in my Gmail after I have received it in my Hotmail.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: How did you set up the forwarding?

Comment: I added a POP3 account in gmail account in the account and imports..

Comment: (Sorry, old question, but...) Collecting email via POP3 in gmail is _not_ forwarding. It would perhaps be much quicker if you did actually _forward_ your email, which outlook.com allows you to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add POP3 Accounts in gmail it checks them periodically. If I am receiving mail frequently (based on the last checks gmail made) it might check every 20 minutes otherwise it might check once an hour.

You can manually request gmail to check your accounts by going to Settings > Accounts and Import > scroll down to "Check mail using POP3" > then click on "Check Mail Now"

Comment: Also found that the google labs allow you to have a refresh button will do the same :)

Comment: Oh. I will have to check that out.

Comment: Yes, Gmail supposedly _learns_ the frequency with which to check emails based on the rate at which you generally receive emails.